# Kotlin Generic Reflection Subclass

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, covariance

I have a function that takes a `Class<GenericType<Constraint>>`. 
When I pass a subclass of that `GenericType<Constraint>` the compiler errors with the message:
`Type Inference Failed. Expected Type Mismatch`

However, if I *cast the type* to it's supertype, it runs fine (with a warning). How to do this without casting?

```
open class Bag<T>

class IntBag: Bag<Int>()

fun testStuff(type: Class<Bag<Int>>) {
    // Do stuff
}

testStuff(IntBag::class.java) // This won't compile
testStuff(IntBag::class.java as Class<Bag<Int>>) // This compiles with a warning, but runs fine
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use out variance:
`fun testStuff(type: Class<out Bag<Int>>)`

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

Answer (score 0):

`Bag<Int>` is effectively different than `IntBag` since they're different classes.

You could utilize a typealias for `IntBag` like so:

```
typealias IntBag = Bag<Int>
```

Answer (score 0):

> BUT if I cast the type to it's supertype, it runs fine (with a warning).

Well, it'll also "run fine" (depending on the internals of `testStuff`) if you do

```
testStuff(String::class.java as Class<Bag<Int>>)
```

Due to type erasure a `Class<String>` can be cast to `Class<Anything>` and this applies to other generic types too. But really, `IntBag::class.java` is a `Class<IntBag>` and *not* a `Class<Bag<Int>>`.

In fact, there are no values of type `Class<Bag<Int>>`; if you want `Class<any subtype of Bag<Int>>`, then Pamela Hill's answer gives the syntax.